# maven release plugin ignores releaseProfile

Tags: maven-2

I am using two profiles: development and production.

Development should be active on default; production should be used when I am releasing.

In my pom.xml I have:

```
[...]
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0-beta-9</version>
<configuration>
  <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
  <goals>deploy</goals>
  <arguments>-Pproduction</arguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
[...]
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>production</id>
    <properties>
      <profile.name>production</profile.name>
    </properties>
    [...]
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>development</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
    <profile.name>development</profile.name>
    </properties>
       [...]
  </profile>
[...]
```

It just does not work.
`useReleaseProfiles` doesn't work either:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-459

The development profile should be always active but not when running `mvn release:perform`.
How do you achieve this?

[UPDATE]:
I have seen with the debug flag that my production profile is used, but development profile is used too, because it is `activeByDefault`. This cant be overridden by the `releaseProfile` argument. It would be nice to force the release plugin to use **only** the "production" profile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `maven-release-plugin` [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) encourages using the `releaseProfiles` configuration parameter to automatically invoke profiles during the release process.

This is a better approach than manually invoking release profiles from the command-line.  One reason, is because the profiles used in the release will be documented in the `pom.xml` and stored with the tagged code.  This makes the build process easier to understand and easier to repeat later, exactly the same way the project was originally released.

If using `maven-release-plugin` older than `2.4` see this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-459) preventing use of the above  mentioned parameter.

Be aware that in case of a multi-module project you'll have to put the "releaseProfiles" configuration in the root pom! See also [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-863) for more information about that.

Comment: @editor, Its better to write that the bug has been fixed, here, as a comment.

Comment: Even with 2.5.1 I still have to specify my profile manually `-Prelease` on the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should simply activate your profiles through a property.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>production</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>build</name>
        <value>release</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    [...]
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>development</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>build</name>
        <value>develop</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    [...]
  </profile>
<profiles>
```

Do your builds by executing something like this

```
mvn -Dbuild=develop package
mvn -Dbuild=develop test

mvn -Dbuild=release release:prepare
mvn -Dbuild=release release:perform
```

Comment: yes, i did already know that it is possible to set the profile like this. But this way it can be forgotton. If you forget it, the released package would contain wrong configuration files and deployment would fail. I would like to enforce the release plugin to use only the given profile.

Comment: It can't be forgotten if you define some properties in the profiles which are required and used by the release plugin.

Comment: I do not understand your last comment. Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: I've tried the 'activate-by-property' approach, it works for `maven package` but for `release:xxx` again the default profile is active.

Answer (score 1):

If you check ["Introduction to Build Profiles"](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), "Deactivating a profile":

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:goal -P !profile-1,!profile-2
```

I guess you could use this to deactivate your default profile?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old post but I came across this issue quite recently. The releaseProfile only worked for me when I set the releaseProfiles to profile called **release**. Any other profile gives same error.

Sample code:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagNameFormat>@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                <allowTimestampedSnapshots>true</allowTimestampedSnapshots>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>release</id>
        <properties>
            <connectionUrl>${scm-base}/tags/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</connectionUrl>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```