# active a profile during release prepare in maven 3 does not work

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I have a need to active a profile during release:prepare.

```
<build>
    <plugins>           
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>              
            <configuration>             
                <arguments>-Prelease</arguments>
                <preparationGoals>clean validate</preparationGoals>
                <goals>test-compile</goals>                 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
    </plugin> 
</build>
```

But when I run:

```
mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true help:active-profiles
```

it never show profile release in active list. and it is not show up on active profile list when I do:

```
mvn release:perform help:active-profiles
```

I could not not use `<releaseProfiles>` since I want this profile to be used in both prepare and perform

Thanks!

Comment: First question: Why do you need a profile activated in release:prepare phase?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I have used in this case is not using the -P argument, but rather triggering the profile through an environment setting using -Denv=release. Then in the POM, I have the profile activation based on the value of env. This has always worked for me. So in the `arguments` parameter, you could put something like

```
<arguments>-Denv=release</arguments>
```

Similar questions can be found here:

- [Profile activation on both release:prepare and release:perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994949/profile-activation-on-both-releaseprepare-and-releaseperform)
- [maven release plugin ignores releaseProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291938/maven-release-plugin-ignores-releaseprofile)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some misunderstanding here: `mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true help:active-profiles` will never show the active profiles used during the release, but it shows the *current* active profiles. `release:prepare` will start another Maven thread (separate executable), and only then the release profile is activated.

In the maven-release-plugin-2.4 a lot has been fixed with regards to profiles, especially for Maven3, since some information was not available anymore when using Maven 2 but now is with Maven 3.
See the [release notes](https://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11144&version=17453)