# Profile activation on both release:prepare and release:perform

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I cannot find a solution for activating some Maven profile on `release:prepare` and `release:perform` (both) goals. Something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
    <goals>deploy</goals>
    <arguments>-Pmy-release</arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

just doesn't work. I know that `releaseProfiles` setting works only during `release:perform` so I just though that `arguments` setting is exactly what I want, but `my-profile` profile is not active during the execution. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate question. Please take a look at this question, it has an answer.
[maven release plugin ignores releaseProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291938/maven-release-plugin-ignores-releaseprofile)

Basically version 2.2.1 of the release plugin adds a `releaseProfiles` parameter that will allow you to define the profiles to enable during release.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html

Unfortunately, it looks like there's a bug that will prohibit it from doing what you want...

**Edit**

One thing that I have used in this case is not using the `-P` argument, but rather triggering the profile through an environment setting using `-Denv=release`. Then in the POM, I have the profile activation based on the value of `env`. This has always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @nwinkler. `releaseProfiles` parameter is related only to `release:perform` goal, so it doesn't work during `release:prepare`. And, you're right, its behaviour is anyway really weird. Your tip with `-Dmy-release` variable is actually my current workaround. I didn't mention it to have my question straight and to not suggest any path of thinking about it. It seems however that this is the only (or at least the best) way of doing that for now. I've already tried `2.3-SNAPSHOT` version of `maven-release-plugin` and stil doesn't work properly. Sad.

Answer (score 10):

-Darguments="-PmyProfile" seems to do the job.

Answer (score 5):

Because maven release plugin start additional instance you have to specify additional arguments. For you case

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>${myReleaseArgs}</arguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and execution

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -DmyReleaseArgs="-Pmy-release -DskipTests=true" -Pmy-release -DskipTests=true
```

and yes it must be duplicated.

Comment: `mvn release:prepare release:perform -Darguments="-Pmy-release -DskipTests=true" -Pmy-release` would do the same thing without needing to add config to the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

It works in Jenkins by activating the profile for both release:prepare and release:perform by setting both properties

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <releaseProfiles>myprofile</releaseProfiles>
        <arguments>-Pmyprofile</arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build >
```

Even though the above works great, I found more useful to use file activated profiles. The old concept with a 'master' profile was causing a problem, as I had the profile in my parent pom. That meant, it was getting activated in every single module, arbitrary.

To solve it, I used the file activation method in profile. It works even better and as a bonus it simplifies the release in Jenkins. In Eclipse, in command line, in Jenkins, aka everywhere, maven detects the file and the maven-release-plugin does not have to be configured. Plus the profile is active only in the right module.

Comment: Adding `<arguments>-Prelease</arguments>` worked for me. Even in maven-release-plugin-3.0.0-M3, the `<releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>` option seems to do nothing.