# Maven release from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, release

I have the following modules in my project,

```
module - 1
module - 2 
module - 3
module - 4
```

In the Jenkins maven release, I have to release only the module - 1 and module - 2.

For this I have created the profile in root pom which includes the module -1  and module -2.

```
<profile>
    <id>jenkins-release</id>
    <modules>
        <module>module - 1</module>
        <module>module - 2</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
```

How can I make this profile to be executed during Jenkins maven release?

specifying the profile (`-P jenkins-release release:prepare release:perform`) under "release goals and options" in Jenkins does not work.

In local it works with:

```
mvn -P jenkins-release release:perform
```

[image]

Comment: You have to remove the space after the `-P`: `-Pjenkins-release release:prepare release:perform`

Comment: @hotzst That doesn't matter i guess. It works in local.  when i try to release in local using "mvn -P jenkins-release release:perform" works.

Comment: What exactly is the output of the jenkins build? Does it create a release for all four modules, or does the build fail?

Comment: @hotzst It build all the modules which i don't want to do. because in some module the release is not required and hence the release plugins are not included.

Comment: Strongly advise you to try building it manually first, and once you can get it work, copy whatever you have to Jenkins, so you do not need to deal with 2 uncertainties (Jenkins + release plugin parameters)

Answer (score 2):

Your local invocation is not the same. You only specified the goal `release:prepare` whereas in Jenkins it's `release:prepare release:perform`.

There are multiple invocations taking place, and therefore you need to use

`-Darguments=-Pjenkins-release`

You'll notice that I omitted the space between `-P` and `jenkins-release`in order to avoid putting the whole thing between quotes, but I'll leave that to you.

Another option would be to use the `releaseProfile` setting for the release plugin.

Please see [Profile activation on both release:prepare and release:perform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994949/profile-activation-on-both-releaseprepare-and-releaseperform) for more details.

It's a bit verbose but you should be activating the profile both with `-P` (for `release:prepare`) and with `-Darguments=...` (for `release:perform`).  Also, make sure you use the latest version of `maven-release-plugin`, as this was buggy a while back.

Like this: `mvn -Darguments=-Pjenkins-release -Pjenkins-release release:prepare release:perform`

Another approach is to have the profile activate on a custom system property (e.g. `-DdoMyRelease=true`) or an environment variable that you set through Jenkins.

Have you explored the `<releaseProfiles>` option? Put it in the root POM if it is from there you are doing your releases.

Comment: Did not help. I have added the screenshot of my jenkins configuration to the question

Comment: where to add the releaseprofile? in root/parent pom? or to all project pom?